# Colored Table Cells

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

i want to color my table cells according to the Value in Column 1, if the values isn´t equal to the value in Column 1 the color should be cyan, but my code doesnt work:

```
table = new JTable(){
           public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int column) {
              TableCellRenderer tcr=null;
               Color c;
               if(column>=1&&getValueAt(row, column)!=null &&getValueAt(row, 1)!=null &&!getValueAt(row, column).equals(getValueAt(row, 1)))
                   c=Color.CYAN;
               else
                   c=Color.white;
                if(getValueAt(row, column) instanceof Boolean) {
                  tcr= super.getDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class);
                } else {
                  tcr=  super.getCellRenderer(row, column);
                }

               tcr.getTableCellRendererComponent(this, getValueAt(row, column), isCellSelected(row, column) , hasFocus(), row, column).setBackground(c);
               return tcr;

            }
            public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column) {
                if(getValueAt(row, column) instanceof Boolean) {
                    return super.getDefaultEditor(Boolean.class);
                } else {
                    return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
                }
            }
    };
          table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
             {"Row1", "1","2","3"},
             {"Row2", "2","2","3"},
             {"Row3", "2","2","2"},
             {"Row3", "2","1","2"}
                           },
            new String[] {"Header1", "Header2","Header3","Header4"}
    ));
```

Comment: Looks like you are setting the background-color of your JTable instead of your Renderer?

Comment: i updated it ihink now it works

Comment: -1 for asking one of the most often asked questions again .... (too lazy to look up a duplicate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decision of whether a cell must be highlighted must be made in the TableCellRenderer. It can not be made in the JTable. So there is (probably) no reason to override the methods in JTable. Instead, you can set the CellRenderer for the columns to be your own implmenentation of the TableCellRenderer.

In this example, the columns 2 and 3 receive a "ColoringCellRenderer". This ColoringCellRenderer will highlight a certain cell if the value in this cell is not null and the same as the value in column 1.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;


public class ColoredTableCells
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(createTable()));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    static JTable createTable()
    {
        class ColoringTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
        {
            ColoringTableCellRenderer()
            {
                setOpaque(true);
            }

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
                int column)
            {
                super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                    table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
                if (highlightCell(table, row, column))
                {
                    setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                }
                else
                {
                    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                }
                return this;
            }

            private boolean highlightCell(JTable table, int row, int column)
            {
                Object thisValue = table.getValueAt(row, column);
                Object referenceValue = table.getValueAt(row, 1);
                if (thisValue != null && referenceValue != null)
                {
                    return thisValue.equals(referenceValue);
                }
                return false;
            }
        }

        JTable table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {
            { "Row1", "1", "2", "3" },
            { "Row2", "2", "2", "3" },
            { "Row3", "2", "2", "2" }, 
            { "Row3", "2", "1", "2" } },
            new String[] { "Header1", "Header2", "Header3", "Header4" }));


        for (int i=2; i<table.getColumnCount(); i++)
        {
            TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            column.setCellRenderer(new ColoringTableCellRenderer());
        }
        return table;
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: The answer was accepted already, but in response to the comments, a different version:

This one uses two classes, "DelegatingTableCellRenderer" and "DelegatingTableCellEditor". These classes each receive the respective delegate, and only set the background color of the cell component that is delivered by the delegate.

This way, the functionality of coloring table cells (for renderers or editors) is decoupled from the actual renderer. Thus, it is possible to color, for example, the background of a the default CellRenderer for `Boolean` values (which shows a JCheckBox).

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.EventObject;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;


public class ColoredTableCells2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(createTable()));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    static JTable createTable()
    {
        JTable table = new JTable()
        {
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) 
            {
                if (column == 0)
                {
                    return Object.class;
                }
                return Boolean.class;
            }
        };

        table.setDefaultEditor(Boolean.class, 
            new DelegatingTableCellEditor(table.getDefaultEditor(Boolean.class)));

        table.setDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class, 
            new DelegatingTableCellRenderer(table.getDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class)));

        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {
            { "Row1", true,  false, true },
            { "Row2", true,  true,  false },
            { "Row3", false, false, true }, 
            { "Row3", false, true,  false } },
            new String[] { "Header1", "Header2", "Header3", "Header4" }));


        return table;
    }


    static class DelegatingTableCellEditor implements TableCellEditor
    {
        private final TableCellEditor delegate;

        DelegatingTableCellEditor(TableCellEditor delegate)
        {
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue()
        {
            return delegate.getCellEditorValue();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent)
        {
            return delegate.isCellEditable(anEvent); 
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent)
        {
            return delegate.shouldSelectCell(anEvent);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean stopCellEditing()
        {
            return delegate.stopCellEditing();
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelCellEditing()
        {
            delegate.cancelCellEditing();
        }

        @Override
        public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l)
        {
            delegate.addCellEditorListener(l);
        }

        @Override
        public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l)
        {
            delegate.removeCellEditorListener(l);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column)
        {

            Component component = 
                delegate.getTableCellEditorComponent(
                    table, value, isSelected, row, column);
            if (component instanceof JComponent)
            {
                JComponent c = (JComponent)component;
                c.setOpaque(true);
            }
            if (highlightCell(table, row, column))
            {
                component.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            }
            else
            {
                component.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }
            return component;
        }

    }


    static class DelegatingTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer          
    {
        private final TableCellRenderer delegate;

        DelegatingTableCellRenderer(TableCellRenderer delegate)
        {
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
            JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
        {
            Component component = 
                delegate.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                    table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            if (component instanceof JComponent)
            {
                JComponent c = (JComponent)component;
                c.setOpaque(true);
            }
            if (highlightCell(table, row, column))
            {
                component.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            }
            else
            {
                component.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }
            return component;
        } 
    }

    private static boolean highlightCell(JTable table, int row, int column)
    {
        if (column == 1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        Object thisValue = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, column);
        Object referenceValue = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1);
        if (thisValue != null && referenceValue != null)
        {
            return thisValue.equals(referenceValue);
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: don't usnderstand both Q and A too, then +1 against downvoters

Comment: @mKorbel: And I don't understand your comment ;-) The question was *"I want to color my table cells according to the Value in Column 1, if the values isn´t equal to the value in Column 1 the color should be cyan"* - OK, my code colors them cyan if they ARE equal, but that can be fixed with a single `!` ...

Comment: @Marco13 is it possible to combine colored cells and the showing of a checkbox instead of true and false?
i mean if the Model ist like
new Object[][] {
            { "Row1", "1", "2", "3" },
            { "Row2", "2", "2", "3" },
            { "Row3", "2", "2", "2" }, 
            { "Row4", true,false,true } }

because if(getValueAt(row, column) instanceof Boolean) {
                    return super.getDefaultEditor(Boolean.class);
makes such a checkbox

Comment: basically correct (+1) just a bit of nitpicking: a) no need to grab the current value again, it's passed in as parameter b) the renderer should better be autark, that is not rely on other code not setting itself as renderer to the compare column c) will break if user re-arraged the columns d) has no visual selection clue (nor other decoration like dnd) - but this is _really_ just a minor side-note, totally fine for example code :-)

Comment: @Jaran I added an EDIT with a "new version", I think this is what you have been asking for in the comment.